Why am I not able to list all the <li> corresponding to the parameter I passed?
I'm web scraping an HTML page, and I want to store in a list all the <li> that have the string "is". However, the code is only storing the first two, and I don't know exactly what I'm doing wrong
I'm using BeautifulSoup to do the scraping
<ul class="fun-facts">
     <li>Owned my dream car in high school <a href="#footer"><sup>1</sup></a></li>
     <li>Middle name is Ronald</li>
     <li>Never had been on a plane until college</li>
     <li>Dunkin Donuts coffee is better than Starbucks</li>
     <li>A favorite book series of mine is <i>Ender's Game</i></li>
     <li>Current video game of choice is <i>Rocket League</i></li>
     <li>The band that I've seen the most times live is the <i>Zac Brown Band</i></li>
   </ul>

My code
import re

fun_facts = webpage.find('ul', attrs={'class', 'fun-facts'})
fun_facts_with_is = fun_facts.find_all('li', string=re.compile("is"))
fun_facts_with_is

Result returned
[<li>Middle name is Ronald</li>,
  <li>Dunkin Donuts coffee is better than Starbucks</li>]

The result I'm looking for:
['Middle name is Ronald',
  'Dunkin Donuts coffee is better than Starbucks',
  "A favorite book series of mine is Ender's Game",
  'Current video game of choice is Rocket League',
  "The band that I've seen the most times live is the Zac Brown Band"]


string= doesn't work when the <li> contains multiple elements.

Because the .string attribute of those elements is None. .string only works when the contents of the element is a single string.

The behaviour is stated in beautifulsoup documentation:

If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what .string should refer to, so .string is defined to be None

In your case thing refers to other tags inside <li>.

To get your results you can modify your code:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_source = """\
<ul class="fun-facts">
     <li>Owned my dream car in high school <a href="#footer"><sup>1</sup></a></li>
     <li>Middle name is Ronald</li>
     <li>Never had been on a plane until college</li>
     <li>Dunkin Donuts coffee is better than Starbucks</li>
     <li>A favorite book series of mine is <i>Ender's Game</i></li>
     <li>Current video game of choice is <i>Rocket League</i></li>
     <li>The band that I've seen the most times live is the <i>Zac Brown Band</i></li>
</ul>"""

webpage = BeautifulSoup(html_source, "html.parser")

fun_facts = webpage.find("ul", attrs={"class", "fun-facts"})

out = []
for li in fun_facts.find_all("li"):
    if "is" in li.text:
        out.append(li.text)

print(out)

Prints:
[
    "Middle name is Ronald",
    "Dunkin Donuts coffee is better than Starbucks",
    "A favorite book series of mine is Ender's Game",
    "Current video game of choice is Rocket League",
    "The band that I've seen the most times live is the Zac Brown Band",
]

